# Reportviewer showing "Report is being generated" endlessly .net

Tags: .net, dll, windows-7, rdlc, reportviewer

I have two forms, placed a `ReportViewer` on a form and the reports it will print in the project.

I call the `Reportviewer` form and displays the print preview if the report on first run, the report prints normally.

Now closing the the print preview form with `Reportviewer` and try to print the same report, it just keeps showing the

> Report is being generated endlessly

I tried to stop the report generating, but it wont stop.

I have to close the app and try to print again, it repeats same issues i mentioned above.

I am running this in `win7 32 bit .net 2.0` and `ReportViewer 8.0`

**EDIT**

This does not happen on the development machine, but in the customers machine.

The ReportViewer was installed using inno setup silently.

Is this a bug?

Comment: You must put the code here to be analised, since this behaviour may be due to a lot of different things. Anyway, are you sure your CLOSING or DISPOSING correctly the resources utilized in that routine?

Comment: Why are you still using .net 2.0?

Comment: Please help with any solution you have

Comment: Upgrade to newer versions of .net and ReportViewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the error.

It happens that I am using ReportViewer v8 in my report design, but the project, which is being developed in vs2008, is referencing ReportViewer v9

All i needed to do was to remove the reference, copy the the two files of ReportViewer v8   `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll` into my output directory and reference those

Thanks for your help